# In array of objects group by one property and count keyword occurrences in another?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have an array of objects

```
[ 
    { hashtag: [ 'yo' ], type: [] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo2' ], type: [] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo3' ], type: [] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ], type: [] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ], type: [] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ], type: [ 'email' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'asdasdasd' ], type: [ 'email' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ], type: [ 'link' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ], type: [ 'link' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'yo7' ], type: [ 'link' ] },
    { hashtag: [ 'book', 'hello', 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link' ] } 
];
```

Each `hashtag` value can contain array of strings. I need to get all array of unique `hashtags` which have exact `type` and count them. Expected output:

```
[ 
    { hashtag: 'yo5', sum: 3 },
    { hashtag: 'yo6', sum: 2 },
    { hashtag: 'yo7', sum: 1 },
    { hashtag: 'book', sum: 1 },
    { hashtag: 'hello', sum: 1 } 
]
```

I wrote code, but it seems for me that it is not enough optimised. Is there way to make it better?

```
const type = 'link';

const enter = [ 
    { hashtag: [ 'yo' ], type: [] },
       ...
    { hashtag: [ 'book', 'hello', 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link' ] } 
];

const filteredByType = enter.filter((el) => {
    return el.type.includes(type)
});

const newArr = [];

filteredByType.map((el) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < el.hashtag.length; i++) {
    const z = newArr.filter((e) => {
        return e.hashtag === el.hashtag[i]
    });
    if (z.length) {
      const p = newArr.findIndex((obj) => {
        return obj.hashtag === el.hashtag[i];
      });
      newArr[p].sum += 1;
    } else {
      newArr.push({
        hashtag: el.hashtag[i],
        sum: 1
      })
    }
  }
});

console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ne04grhv/13/) is working example

Comment: If only unique, `type` values should be counted, shouldn't `hashtag: 'yo5'` have respective `sum: 2`, since `'email'` and `'link'` are only 2 unique values?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it should be counted for exact `type`, I fixed a bit my question. result in my case is correct

Comment: Then, what do you mean by *'which have exact type'*?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov in my code I pass it as const `type = 'link'` in first line. So I need: from array where type is `link` get all hashtags and sum number of objects containing this hashtag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *sum* you actually mean *count*, you may employ `Map` together with `Array.prototype.reduce()` to group your array by `hashtag` value.

So, assuming your `type` does not contain duplicate items, you may end up with something, like that:

```js
const src=[{hashtag:["yo"],type:[]},{hashtag:["yo2"],type:[]},{hashtag:["yo3"],type:[]},{hashtag:["yo4"],type:[]},{hashtag:["yo4"],type:[]},{hashtag:["yo5"],type:["email"]},{hashtag:["yo5"],type:["link"]},{hashtag:["asdasdasd"],type:["email"]},{hashtag:["yo5"],type:["link"]},{hashtag:["yo6"],type:["link"]},{hashtag:["yo6"],type:["link"]},{hashtag:["yo7"],type:["link"]},{hashtag:["book","hello","yo5"],type:["link"]}],

      groupSearch = _type => 
        [...src
          .reduce((acc, {hashtag, type}) => {
            const increment = +type.includes(_type)
            increment &&
            hashtag.forEach(tag => {
              const group = acc.get(tag)
              group
                ? group.sum += increment
                : acc.set(tag, {hashtag:tag, sum: increment})
            })
            return acc
          }, new Map)
          .values()
        ]
        
      
      
console.log(groupSearch('link'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: I don't see in your code where you consider that it should have exact `type`. But it is interesting how you used Map and Set. I will try to use it in my code

Comment: @angelzzz : I got your point and adjusted my solution to deliver exactly the expected output.

Comment: @angelzzz : consider the little escape hatch that I added in the latest edit of my answer, which boosts the performance dramatically

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), count the occurences and buit a new array from it.

```js
const
    getCount = (array, type) => Array.from(
        data.reduce(
            (map, o) => o.type.includes(type)
                ? o.hashtag.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), map)
                : map,
            new Map
        ),
        ([hashtag, sum]) => ({ hashtag, sum })
    ),
    data = [{ hashtag: ['yo'], type: [] }, { hashtag: ['yo2'], type: [] }, { hashtag: ['yo3'], type: [] }, { hashtag: ['yo4'], type: [] }, { hashtag: ['yo4'], type: [] }, { hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['email'] }, { hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['link'] }, { hashtag: ['asdasdasd'], type: ['email'] }, { hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['link'] }, { hashtag: ['yo6'], type: ['link'] }, { hashtag: ['yo6'], type: ['link'] }, { hashtag: ['yo7'], type: ['link'] }, { hashtag: ['book', 'hello', 'yo5'], type: ['link'] }];

console.log(getCount(data, 'link'));
console.log(getCount(data, 'email'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. It should take in consideration type. But solution is very useful

Comment: @angelzzz, sorry, i missed the `type` part. please see edit.

Comment: Thank you! Works great

Answer (score 1):

i did that, no idea how it performed ...?

```js
const data = 
  [ { hashtag: [ 'yo' ],        type: []       } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo2' ],       type: []        } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo3' ],       type: []         } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ],       type: []          } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ],       type: []           } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'email' ]   } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'link' ]     } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'asdasdasd' ], type: [ 'email' ]     } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'link' ]       } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ],       type: [ 'link' ]        } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ],       type: [ 'link' ]         } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo7' ],       type: [ 'link' ]          } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'book', 'hello', 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link'] } 
  ]

const getCount = ( arr, typeK ) =>  
    arr.reduce((res, {hashtag,type }) => [...res,...(type.includes(typeK)?hashtag:[])],[])
      .sort()
      .reduce((res,val,i,{ [i -1]: last }) =>
          {
          if (last === val ) res[res.length -1].sum ++
          else res.push({hastag:val,sum:1})
          return res
          },[]) 

console.log('link =', getCount(data, 'link'))
console.log('email =', getCount(data, 'email'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: As for performance, I would expect that it may be relatively slow because of `.sort()` (which is pretty expensive on its own). I may be wrong, though, can't compare that to the others because it doesn't provide the expected output.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov indeed I completely missed this point. I corrected ;)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov expected output is provided in original question and in jsfiddle

Comment: @angelzzz : I meant that *this particular answer* did not provide the output that you have specified as expected, that's why it can't be compared apple to apple with other solutions, as they fulfill the desired output.

Comment: However, one assumption [I have made correctly](https://jsbench.me/5ykkfzbb0s/1): above solution is one of the slowest, while the fastest are the one posted by Nina, and the one posted by me - at different benchmark runs its either hers or mine show the fastest performance.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes I can believe that this solution is the slowest, the one proposed by Nina impressed me, as often. I also found a third solution, allowing to avoid sorting, but I will not add it here because even if it can be an improvement, the performance will not be there

Answer (score 1):

An other way...

```js
const data = 
  [ { hashtag: [ 'yo' ],        type: []       } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo2' ],       type: []        } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo3' ],       type: []         } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ],       type: []          } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo4' ],       type: []           } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'email' ]   } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'link' ]     } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'asdasdasd' ], type: [ 'email' ]     } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo5' ],       type: [ 'link' ]       } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ],       type: [ 'link' ]        } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo6' ],       type: [ 'link' ]         } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'yo7' ],       type: [ 'link' ]          } 
  , { hashtag: [ 'book', 'hello', 'yo5' ], type: [ 'link'] } 
  ]

const getCount = ( arr, typeK ) =>  
  Object.entries(arr.reduce((r,{hashtag,type})=>
    {
    if (type.includes(typeK))
      hashtag.forEach(h=>{ r[h]=(r[h] ?? 0); r[h]++ })
    return r
    },{})).map(([k,v])=> ({hashtag:k,sum:v}))

console.log('link =', getCount(data, 'link'))
console.log('email =', getCount(data, 'email'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And this one too.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov indeed I completely missed this point here too. I corrected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using a double-`reduce`.  We filter out those values that don't include our target type, fold the result into an object like `{yo5: 3, yo6: 2, yo7: 1, book: 1, hello: 1}`, take the entries of that and map these into your `{hashtag, sum}` format:

```js
const tagCountByType = (targetType) => (xs) => 
  Object .entries (xs .filter (({type}) => type .includes (targetType))
     .reduce (
       (a, {hashtag}) => hashtag .reduce ((a, tag) => ((a [tag] = (a[tag] || 0) + 1), a), a), 
       {}
     )
  ) .map (([hashtag, sum]) => ({hashtag, sum}))

const input = [{hashtag: ['yo'], type: []}, {hashtag: ['yo2'], type: []}, {hashtag: ['yo3'], type: []}, {hashtag: ['yo4'], type: []}, {hashtag: ['yo4'], type: []}, {hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['email']}, {hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['link']}, {hashtag: ['asdasdasd'], type: ['email']}, {hashtag: ['yo5'], type: ['link']}, {hashtag: ['yo6'], type: ['link']}, {hashtag: ['yo6'], type: ['link']}, {hashtag: ['yo7'], type: ['link']}, {hashtag: ['book', 'hello', 'yo5'], type: ['link']}]

console .log ('link:', tagCountByType ('link') (input))
console .log ('email:', tagCountByType ('email') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

As others have pointed out, `sum` is a strange choice of words here.  `count` would make more sense.